# Mobile Robot doesn't reach nav goal within goal tolerances in nav2

Tags: robotics, ros2

I have found no resources on this online (or I'm just that bad at searching) so I thought I could get this answered here.

I have a differential drive robot that I am simulating in nvidia's Isaac sim. I'm using the navigation2 stack in order for the mobile robot to navigate its surroundings and pick up objects within the environment. Everything works fine except for one minor detail.

I noticed in testing that the mobile robot does not completely reach the navigation goals that are set for it (i.e. the controller claims to have reached its goal when the base_frame of the robot fails to reach the set goal point).

Obviously this is generally fine and understandable since the controller must prevent the robot from oscillating around the goal point, but after checking positions several times I realized that the robot doesn't even reach the goal within the specified tolerance of the goal checker (currently set at 1mm).

Here is the navigation parameters file:

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_link"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: 0.4
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan
    map_topic: map
    set_initial_pose: true
    always_reset_initial_pose: false
    first_map_only: false
    initial_pose:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      yaw: 0.0

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 20
    default_server_timeout: 40
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
    - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
    - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugin: ["general_goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    general_goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.001
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.001
      stateful: true
    FollowPath:
      # Rotation Shim Controller parameters
      plugin: "nav2_rotation_shim_controller::RotationShimController"
      primary_controller: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
      angular_dist_threshold: 0.785
      forward_sampling_distance: 2.0
      rotate_to_heading_angular_vel: 1.8
      max_angular_accel: 3.2
      simulate_ahead_time: 1.0
      # DWB parameters
      time_steps: 56
      model_dt: 0.05
      batch_size: 2000
      vx_std: 0.2
      vy_std: 0.2
      wz_std: 0.4
      vx_max: 0.5
      vx_min: -0.35
      vy_max: 0.5
      wz_max: 1.9
      iteration_count: 1
      prune_distance: 1.7
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      temperature: 0.3
      gamma: 0.015
      motion_model: "DiffDrive"
      visualize: false
      reset_period: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
      TrajectoryVisualizer:
        trajectory_step: 5
        time_step: 3
      AckermannConstrains:
        min_turning_r: 0.2
      critics: ["ConstraintCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      ConstraintCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 4.0
      GoalCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.0
      GoalAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 3.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.4
      PreferForwardCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.4
      ObstaclesCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        repulsion_weight: 1.5
        critical_weight: 20.0
        consider_footprint: false
        collision_cost: 10000.0
        collision_margin_distance: 0.1
        near_goal_distance: 0.5
        inflation_radius: 0.55 # (only in Humble)
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 # (only in Humble)
      PathAlignCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 14.0
        max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.05
        trajectory_point_step: 3
        threshold_to_consider: 0.40
        offset_from_furthest: 20
      PathFollowCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        offset_from_furthest: 5
        threshold_to_consider: 0.6
      PathAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 2.0
        offset_from_furthest: 4
        threshold_to_consider: 0.40
        max_angle_to_furthest: 1.0

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 10.0
      publish_frequency: 10.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: True
      width: 10
      height: 10
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.5
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer", "js_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 0.4
        inflation_radius: 0.25
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      js_layer:
        plugin: "jackstand_objective_costmap_plugin::JSLayer"
        enabled: true
        costmap_resolution: 0.05
        target_clear_radius: 0.5
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 10.0
      publish_frequency: 10.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: True
      width: 200
      height: 200
      robot_radius: 0.5
      resolution: 0.05
      # origin_x: -100.0
      # origin_y: -100.0
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer", "js_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 10.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 10.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      js_layer:
        plugin: "jackstand_objective_costmap_plugin::JSLayer"
        enabled: true
        costmap_resolution: 0.05
        target_clear_radius: 0.5
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: "test_map_occupancy_params.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5000
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_theta_star_planner/ThetaStarPlanner"
      how_many_corners: 8
      w_euc_cost: 1.0
      w_traversal_cost: 2.0
      w_heuristic_cost: 1.0

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 5.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.2
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200
```

I have messed with the settings for hours now and have seen no change in the behavior of the mobile robot. Setting the goal_tolerance lower than the default doesn't change anything with respect to how far the robot stops away from its goal.

I figured that setting the tolerances in the goal_checker would make it so that the robot would need to move closer to the navigation goal before being satisfied but that isn't the case.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Or know how I can get the robot to move it's base_link closer to the navigation goal?

---

Update:

So it looks like nav2 isn't even pulling any of the goal_checker_plugin parameters. I set the xy_goal_tolerance much higher than the default (1 meter) and it had no effect either. Any idea why it's not using these?